# delete Duplicate Row SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server .  i have creating SQL table have more than 20000 lines. i have Filter duplicate Using Following Query.

```
SELECT
    Entity,ExpenseType,Amount,Description,APSupplierID,ExpenseReportID,Employee,ExpenseDate,COUNT(*)
FROM
    TotalsByGLCenter
GROUP BY
    Entity,ExpenseType,Amount,Description,APSupplierID,ExpenseReportID,Employee,ExpenseDate
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

now I want to delete Duplicate from SQL Server How to add delete Following above Query ?

Comment: Which is your `Primary Key` in your table?

Comment: All the duplicate entries or do you want to retain one of them?

Comment: All the Duplicates Entires   P.Salmon

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
;WITH cte
         AS (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY Entity,ExpenseType,Amount,Description,APSupplierID,ExpenseReportID,Employee,ExpenseDate ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RowNum
             FROM   TotalsByGLCenter)
    Delete FROM cte
    WHERE  RowNum > 1;
```

The “ROW_NUMBER()” in the above query returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition. The “ORDER BY” clause determines the order in which the ROW_NUMBER value is assigned to the rows in a partition. The “PARTITION BY” clause used here to divide the result set into partitions;

The new column RowNum shows row numbers of the duplicate rows.

In case if you want to see the duplicate rows you can use **select** instead of **delete**

```
   ;WITH cte
         AS (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY Entity,ExpenseType,Amount,Description,APSupplierID,ExpenseReportID,Employee,ExpenseDate ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RowNum,Entity,ExpenseType,Amount,Description,APSupplierID,ExpenseReportID,Employee,ExpenseDate 
             FROM   TotalsByGLCenter)
    Select * FROM cte
    WHERE  RowNum > 1;
```

Comment: @P.Salmon if you are not clear with the answer pls look go through this article http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/23/sql-server-2005-2008-delete-duplicate-rows/

Comment: The link does not explain how it works.Can you explain or provide the appropriate link? what happens if there is more than one table in select statement?

Comment: sorry  @thenna there was a comma added by mistake. Check now

Comment: The link does not say how deleting from CTE deletes from actual table

Comment: This could explain, i think: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql notes that with-subquery must be "updatable and reference exactly one base table in the FROM clause of the view definition. For more information about updatable views, see CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql)."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (simplified) example

```
drop table t
create  table t (id int)

insert into t values (1),(1),(1),(2),(3),(3)

;WITH CTE AS(
  select id,count(*) as dupes
  from t
  group by t.id
  having count(*) > 1

)
DELETE  t where t.id  in (select  cte.id from cte)
```

result

```
1> select * from t
2> ;
3> go
id
-----------
          2
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also create a new regular table with the same structure, insert distinct data in that table, then delete your original table and rename new table to the same name as original table had